# Representation type of certain tensor product algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory

Given a quiver algebra $A=kQ/I$ with underlying quiver $Q$ being a linear oriented Dynkin quiver of type $\mathcal{A}$. Such an algebra is uniquely determined by the sequence $[c_0,c_1,...,c_{n-1}]$ when $c_i$ is the dimension of the projective indecomposable module at point $i$ and $n$ the number of simple modules.
Let $B=K[x]/(x^r)$. For which parameters $c_i$ and $r$ as above is the algebra $C=A \otimes_K B$ representation-finite and can the Auslander-Reiten quivers be nicely described in general?

Comment: In case $I=0$ this is true if and only if we are in one of the following $3$ cases a) $n=1$ and $r$ is arbitrary, b) $n=2$ and $r=2,3$ c) $n=3$ and $r=2$, d) $n$ is arbitrary and $r=1$. This is for example stated in Proposition 13.1 of [Geiß, Leclerc, Schröer: Quivers with relations for symmetrizable Cartan matrices I: Foundations]

Comment: My computer suggests the same. r=2 and [2,2,2...,2,1] should always be representation-finite.

Comment: This is true since the corresponding algebra $C$ is special biserial and there are no band modules.

Comment: Yes, this algebra has in fact many more secrets!